# Stopping PCM sample causes click

Tags: c, audio, wav, pcm, waveform

I'm generating a wav file from an array of samples. I noticed that if I start and then stop copying a waveform, it produces a "click" sound. Here's a simple example, where I periodically copy a sine wave followed by no sound (16 bit signed stereo pcm at 44100 hz):

```
int c, counter = 0;
short *wavdat = malloc(numberOfSamples * 2);
for(c = 0; c < numberOfSamples * 2; c += 2){
    counter++;
    if(counter % 10000 < 5000){
        wavdat[c] = sinf(counter * .1f) * 16000;
        wavdat[c+1] = wavdat[c];
    }else{
        wavdat[c] = wavdat[c+1] = 0;
    }
}
```

Here's what the wav looks like in audacity, zoomed in at a point where the sine wave is cut off:

[image]

The sharp spike at the end seems to be the cause of the click sound I hear. Why does this cause a click sound instead of just stopping the sound instantaneously? How can I stop a sound without the audible click? I need to stop copying samples at an exact time, so I'm not sure I can fade them out.

This problem happens to me even with a much more complex waveform (such as stopping a voice clip).

Here's the recorded sound file if anyone's interested: http://clyp.it/yc2mpqni

Comment: Is there any chance that you could pass along all the code? I am curious to see how an entire wave file is built.

Comment: I didn't write the wav writing code myself, I got it from a simple C++ function here: http://ltheory.com/blog/writeWav.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any abrupt spike in a PCM waveform is in fact a click.

If you know in advance how many samples you're going to copy out, you can start fading them out early -- a linear cutoff slope over 0.05 seconds of time is a good starting point.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to avoid the clicking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stop the sample at the zero-crossing point.  That will eliminate the spike.

Comment: Truncation at zero-crossing is much better than truncation at a peak, but it still can still carry unwanted noise.